# magento 2.4 difference between input argument and option in console commands

Tags: magento2, command-line, console, option

on magento 2 when we create a console command, we can add arguments and/or option. But what is the difference between the two? In which cases should we use one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options have a flag. Arguments have no flag.

> bin/magento‌ do:something‌ --email="me@me.com"

do:something = Argument

--email = Option

(accept the anwser if solved your doubt)